# Should we be using setTargetFragment()? I thought Fragments should not be communicating with each other

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-dialogfragment

The android developer tutorials recommend me using the host activities of fragments to pass around data and whatnot, so why is there a set/get target fragment method?

My application thus far contains a host activity, and a fragment, which has a button that launches a `DialogFragment`, in which there is a button that launches ANOTHER `DialogFragment`. Using `setTargetFragment/getTargetFragment` has made this whole ordeal somewhat confusing though, so I am thinking of reimplementing to let my main activity handle `DialogFragment.show` methods through my main fragment's custom interface.

Is this the right way of thinking? Or is there no harm in using `setTargetFragment`? Can anyone provide good and bad examples of using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is implicit harm in using setTargetFragment, however, I would only use it in very specific circumstances. For example, if the target fragment is *only* going to ever be used by the fragment (taking into account object reuse and designing your classes to be reusable when possible) and even then, sparingly.

By using them too much, you will end up with what you're seeing - confusing code that is hard to follow and maintain.  On the outset, by marshaling everything through your activity you maintain a "flat" hierarchy that is simple to follow and maintain.

I think the decision to use setTargetFragment or not is a coding-style/philosophical one that, with wisdom and experience, it "feels" right or wrong.  Maybe on your case, by evidence that you are questioning your older code, you are gaining that wisdom :)

Comment: I suppose my guts were telling me right. Thanks for the suggestions. I'll start reimplementing now... :P

Comment: If you use setTargetFragment via callback interface you won't couple fragments to each other - however if you cast to a specific Fragment, then I would consider that a bad idea because it introduces tight coupling.

Answer (score 6):

Also, you may end up with exception of no target fragment found in fragment manager. This happens if after rotation (or other config change) your target fragment will not be readded to the fragment manager by the time when caller fragment will be adding.

Imagine you have some sort of Confirmation fragment which you add from `MainFragment` as so:

```
ConfirmationFragment frag = new ConfirmationFragment();
frag.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
getFragmentManager().beginFragmentTransaction().add(R.id.container, frag).commit();
```

Now on some confirmation button click you invoke a method from `MainFragment` by calling:

```
((MainFragment)this.getTargetFragment()).onUserSelectedGoodButton();
```

This is pretty and simple, but if you will rotate the screen and for some reason `ConfirmationFragment` will be added to `FragmentManager` before `MainFragment`, exception will be thrown, stating that target fragment is not found in the fragment manager

Comment: All you have to do is save your target fragment in onSaveInstanceState - then you can retrieve it in onCreate if savedInstance is != null. I faintly remember having read, that if you replace a fragment it might be problematic, rather than hiding the original one and adding the new fragment on top of it.

Comment: @AgentKnopf "save your target fragment in onSaveInstanceState"? What does this mean? "Saving" fragments is the job of the fragment manager. I never heard before that somebody tried to "save" a fragment. A dialog will never recreate it's caller.

Comment: You just have to use the child fragmentmanager of the caller / targetfragment when creating the dialog. Then you can rotate as much as you want - there won't be thrown any exception.